# socket.io with mern stack Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

hello guys im trying with online/offline system:

backend:

```
var userCount = 0;
var onlineuserList = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  userCount++;
  io.sockets.emit('userCount', { userCount: userCount });

  socket.on('login', function (data) {
    onlineuserList = onlineuserList.filter(user=> user !== data);
    onlineuserList.push(data);

    setInterval(function(){
      io.sockets.emit('onlineuserList', onlineuserList); 
    }, 1000);
  });

  socket.on('logout', function (data) {
      onlineuserList = onlineuserList.filter(user=> user !== data)
      io.sockets.emit('onlineuserList', { onlineuserList: onlineuserList });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    userCount--;
    io.sockets.emit('userCount', { userCount: userCount });
  });
});
```

frontend:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('onlineuserList', (onlineuserList) => {
        if(onlineuserList.length > 0){
          onlinesetuserList(onlineuserList && onlineuserList);
          setStatus(onlineuserList && onlineuserList.includes(props.id));
        } else {
          onlinesetuserList([]);
          setStatus(false);
        }
    });

    return () => socket.off('onlineuserList', onlineuserList);
  }, []);
```

Everything working only, but in console log i getting this error:
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

And one more question is it good and secure to set setinterval on every second in backend?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not providing the original callback function to the socket.off method, so the socket listener doesn't get cleaned up as the component unmounts.

I would suggest the following fix:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const onlineUserListHandler = (onlineuserList) => {
        if(onlineuserList.length > 0){
            onlinesetuserList(onlineuserList && onlineuserList);
            setStatus(onlineuserList && onlineuserList.includes(props.id));
        } else {
            onlinesetuserList([]);
            setStatus(false);
        }
    }

    socket.on('onlineuserList', onlineUserListHandler);

    return () => socket.off('onlineuserList', onlineUserListHandler);
}, []);
```

Comment: thank you this solved my issue, what you think about server code is it good to use setinterval on every seconds? I ask because of the number of requests, maybe they could cause the server to crash?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634644/react-js-more-functions-in-one-file-react-unmounted please check this :)